# Convert XML formatted list into PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a URL that returns an XML formatted list

i have put this URL in a variable:

```
$url = 'urlHere.xml';
```

i need to be able to return the results and list them in PHP (for example in a select element)

i have tried using the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

but im not too sure what would be next

the start of the XML file looks like:

```
<interface-response>
<tldlist>
<tld>
<tld>com</tld>
</tld>
<tld>
<tld>net</tld>
</tld>
```

Comment: the next step would be to access values inside `$xml`, most likely you'd use a `foreach`

Comment: That function will return an object of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), which represent your xml file

Comment: Can you post your xml file?

Comment: Are you looking for [Basic SimpleXML usage (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is our xml file stored in the same dir

**sms.xml**

```
<?xml    ?>

<sms>

<body>
Hi Doe! whats going on?
</body>
</sms>
```

Now lets get the contant of sms.xml  in php

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("sms.xml");

    echo $xml->body;
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Hi Doe! whats going on?
```